# category_name not working in WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, wp-query, taxonomy

I have a custom post type and I wanted to show posts just from a certain category but its not working.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
// Reset post data.
wp_reset_postdata();
$photo_group = 0; // For prettyPhoto grouping.
$count = 1; // For unique id of gallery item

// Build query based on site option value.
$num_of_gallery_posts = get_option( 'st_gallery_posts_per_page' );
if ( '' == $num_of_gallery_posts || 'show all' == $num_of_gallery_posts ) :
    $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=gallery&category_name=destaque&posts_per_page=-1' );

else :

    $num_per_page = (int) $num_of_gallery_posts;
                                        $cat_id = get_cat_ID('destaque');

    $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=gallery&category_name=destaque&posts_per_page=' . $num_per_page . '&paged=' . get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
endif;

//Start the WordPress Loop after querying the posts.
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

Comment: ___What___ doesn't work? ___Where___ does it fail? Your query looks fine to me, and works with known good values. I don't think that is where the problem is, or your database does not look like you think it does.

Comment: You're grabbing posts from a custom post type -- `gallery` -- but using the WordPress native `category`.  Are you sure your posts use WordPress's `category`, or is there a custom taxonomy attached to your custom post type? If the latter, see the [Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) section of the WP_Query docs (especially the `tax_query` part).